# How to Sort all the pages using bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-ui

I have used **BootStrap-ui** for pagination and for sorting. When I click on any column to sort the data it is only sorting the first page. Can somebody help me to sort all the pages at once when I click on any column?

My Code:

```
<tbody>   
  <tr data-ng-repeat="ci in cartItemsarr | orderBy:sort.sortingOrder:sort.reverse| filter:paginate">

</tbody>

<div class="pull-right">                    
     <uib-pagination total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentPage" max-size="5" boundary-links="true" 
          items-per-page="numPerPage" class="pagination-sm" num-pages="numPages" />
</div>
```

Comment: My Code:  

 <tbody>   
  <tr data-ng-repeat="ci in cartItemsarr | orderBy:sort.sortingOrder:sort.reverse| filter:paginate">
                             
                            
</tbody>

 <div class="pull-right">                    
                    <uib-pagination total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentPage" max-size="5" boundary-links="true" 
                        items-per-page="numPerPage" class="pagination-sm" num-pages="numPages" />
                </div>

Comment: Are you using server side paging or client side?

Comment: client side using angular js

Comment: Any help on this?

Comment: Could you create a plunker? the order of sort and filter is correct. Need more info to see what is wrong